# in python pandas how to i calculate a count when the column is also the counted Value

Tags: python, pandas

see below example. How can i get the same with `pivot_table`

```
print(results.pivot_table(index='Instrument ID', columns=  'Match', values='Match', aggfunc=np.count_nonzero))
```

Excel table where it works:

[image: pivot table excel]

if i add the `columns = 'Match'` then it breaks. Without it it displays the total only. So i need to add the Match as a column but then the `'values'` does not like 'match' as a field and it breaks again. Thank you for any answers!

I cannot get the `pivot_table` to work as expected.

Comment: pvt = test_df.pivot_table(index='names', columns='male_female', aggfunc={'Salary': np.count_nonzero})   this is that i use always.

Comment: Well the difference here is that i need the Match column to also be in the counter.  You are using 3 different fields, i only need 2 fields for the pivot. So i changed it to this print(results.pivot_table(index='Instrument ID', columns=  'Match', aggfunc={'Match': np.count_nonzero})) but i get this error now '<' not supported between instances of 'ComparisonResult' and 'ComparisonResult'
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'ComparisonResult' and 'ComparisonResult'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: please provide a fully reproducible input and the matching expected output, what you expected is currently ambiguous

Comment: i think the output is in the excel file screenshot. I will give you the input here if it helps you: 
Instrument ID Match
FR0000120693 ComparisonResult.NoMatch
FR0000120693 ComparisonResult.Unimportant
FR0000120693 ComparisonResult.NoMatch
FR0000120693 ComparisonResult.NoMatch
FR0000120693 ComparisonResult.NoMatch
FR0000120693 ComparisonResult.NoMatch
FR0000120693 ComparisonResult.NoMatch
FR0000120693 ComparisonResult.NoMatch
FR0000120693 ComparisonResult.NoMatch
FR0000120693 ComparisonResult.NoMatch
FR0000120693 ComparisonResult.Unimportant
FR0000120693 ComparisonResult.NoMatch

Comment: Somehow  the input does not appear correctly formated . It's basically 2 columns but it's displayed as a continuous line but if you copy paste into excel it should fix itself

Comment: Also the Match is formatted a boolean. I tried to make it string but still failed on the panda pivot_{table. Note that i want to count the number of occurrences. i am not summing up. Exactly as as per the Excel pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the additional columns after, it doesn't need to be done within the pivot table:

```py
out = df.pivot_table(columns="Match", index="Instrument ID",
                     values="Match", aggfunc=np.count_nonzero)
# Grand Totals
out["Grand Total"] = out.sum(axis=1)
out.loc["Grand Total"] = out.sum(axis=0)

# or with groupby and unstack

out = df.groupby(["Instrument ID", "Match"])\
    .agg({"Match": np.count_nonzero}).unstack()
# Grand Totals
out["Grand Total"] = out.sum(axis=1)
out.loc["Grand Total"] = out.sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: "Error Grouper for 'Match' not 1-dimensional" is the result of the pivot_table option. The groupby seems to work better though and gives me what i need. Thank you!